# catch https requests via CharlesProxy received error

Tags: ssl, https

I want to use CharlesProxy to sniffer https requests ,i've installed the cert in my iphone, and set using ssl in CharlesProxy,but when the app make requests, Charles Proxy displays:Received Close notify during handshake

[image: this is the error in charles proxy]

Comment: I have a similar issue, except for me it is "SSL: Received fatal alert: close_notify". What version of Charles are you using? Also, what Java version?

Comment: @ETL my java version is "1.6.0_65", and my charles version is 3.8.1

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions of Charles, the SSL certificate must be installed on the device from charlesproxy.com/getssl, while the device is already being proxied through the Charles instance that you want to use.

(As opposed to installing the SSL certificate from charlesproxy.com/charles.crt, with or without being proxied.)

Did you do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
In Charles go to the Help menu and choose "SSL Proxying > Install Charles Root Certificate". A window will appear warning you that the CA Root certificate is not trusted.

Click the "Install Certificate" button to launch the Certificate Import Wizard. The certificate must be imported into the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" certificate store, so override the automatic certificate store selection.

Complete the wizard and your Charles Root Certificate is now installed. You may need to restart IE before the installation takes affect.